# php ajax dependent dropdown not loading data from table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a dependent dropdown using php and ajax. What I am expecting is when the 'Make' of car is selected the relevant car models should automatically load on the 'Model' dropdown. I have manged to do the preloading of 'Make' of cars. But the 'Model' dropdown remains empty. I have used a single tale and in sql statement used (select model where make= selected make). here is my code

**php**

```
<form method="GET">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="make" id="make">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>--Select Make--</option>
                                        <?php
                                            $stmt=$pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT make FROM cars  WHERE cartype='general' ");
                                        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?= $row['make']; ?>"> <?= $row['make']; ?></option>
                                        
                                        <?php  } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="model" id="model">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>--Select Model--</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
.......
....
.....
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
           // alert("Hello");
        $(#make).change(function(){
            var make = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"filter_action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{Make:make},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#model").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

**filter_action.php**

```
<?php 
    include('db_config2.php');
    $output='';
    $stmt=$pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM cars  WHERE cartype='general' AND make= '".$_POST['Make']."'");
    $output .='<option value="" disabled selected>--Select Model--</option>';
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $output .='<option value="'.$row["model"].'">'.$row["model"].'</option>'    ;
        }
        echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: This `$(#make)` should in quotes i.e :`$("#make")` . Also, check browser console is there any other errors ?

Comment: You have made your SQL vulnerable to injection attacks by directly embedding user supplied input data

Comment: @Swati thanks. yes I have changed it to $("#make") but the result is still the same

Comment: what you get the reult??

Comment: @KUMAR no, the 'make' dropdown is working but the 'model'  dropdown is still empty

Comment: can you load latest `jquery.min.js` cdn ??

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

There appeared to be a couple of mistakes in the Javascript that would have been obvious in the developer console and your PHP had left the mySQL server vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    
        // The string should be within quotes here
        $('#make').change(function(e){
            var make = $(this).val();
            
            $.ajax({
                url:"filter_action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{'Make':make},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#model").html(data);
                };//this needed to be closed
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The direct use of user supplied data within the sql opened your db to sql injection attacks. To mitigate this you need to adopt `"Prepared Statements"` - as you are using PDO anyway this should be a matter of course.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['Make'] ) ){
    
        # The placeholders and associated values to be used when executing the sql cmd
        $args=array(
            ':type'     =>  'general',  # this could also be dynamic!
            ':make'     =>  $_POST['Make']
        );
        # Prepare the sql with suitable placeholders
        $sql='select distinct `model` from `cars`  where `cartype`=:type and `make`=:make';
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
        
        # commit the query
        $stmt->execute( $args );
        
        # Fetch the results and populate output variable
        $data=array('<option disabled selected hidden>--Select Model--');
        while( $rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )$data[]=sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s', $rs->model );
        
        # send it to ajax callback
        exit( implode( PHP_EOL,$data ) );
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help. unfortunately it did not work. i appreciate you suggestion for prepared stmt to prevent sql injection. basically I copied your code but, still no result.

Comment: can you open the dev console and report any errors observed?

Comment: I am not sure if you would like the idea. I am coding on cpanel, not on local server.

Comment: ? NFI - never seen cPanel. Was just wondering if there were any js errors

Answer (score 0):

I have try this using `php pdo`.

first i have create a 3 files.

1. `db.php`
2. `htmlDropdown.php`
3. `modelAjax.php`

here, `db.php` file can contain my database connection code. and `htmlDropdown.php` file contain my dropdown for car and models. and `modelAjax.php` file contain ajax to fetch all models.

db.php

```
<?php

$host_name = 'localhost';
$user_name = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'stackoverflow';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$db_name;", $user_name, $password);

?>
```

htmlDropdown.php

```
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cars</title>
    <!-- jQuery cdn link -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Ajax cdn link -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxy/1.6.1/scripts/jquery.ajaxy.min.js" integrity="sha512-bztGAvCE/3+a1Oh0gUro7BHukf6v7zpzrAb3ReWAVrt+bVNNphcl2tDTKCBr5zk7iEDmQ2Bv401fX3jeVXGIcA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $car_sql = 'SELECT car_name FROM cars';  //select all cars query
        $cars_statement = $conn->prepare($car_sql);
        $cars_statement->execute();
    ?>
    <select name="car" id="car">
        <option value="">Cars</option>
        <?php
            while ($cars = $cars_statement->fetch()) { // fetch all cars data
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cars['car_name']; ?>"><?php echo $cars['car_name']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <select name="model" id="model">
        <option value="">Model</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#car').on("change", function () {

            let car = $(this).val(); // car value

            $.post("http://local.stackoverflowanswer1/cars/modelAjax.php", { car_name : car }, function (data, status) { // ajax post send car name in modelAjax.php file
                
                let datas = JSON.parse(data); // convert string to json object

                let options = '';

                options = '<option>Model</option>';

                $.each(datas.model, function (key, value) {
                    options += "<option>"+value.modal_name+"</option>";
                });

                $('#model').html(options);

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

modelAjax.php

```
<?php

include "db.php";

if ($_POST['car_name']) 
{
    $car_id_sql = "SELECT id FROM cars WHERE car_name LIKE ?"; // get id from given car name
    $id_statement = $conn->prepare($car_id_sql);
    $id_statement->execute([$_POST['car_name']]);

    $id = $id_statement->fetch();

    $model_sql = "SELECT modal_name FROM models WHERE car_id = ?"; // get model name from given id
    $model_statement = $conn->prepare($model_sql);
    $model_statement->execute([$id['id']]);

    $models = $model_statement->fetchAll();

    echo json_encode(["model" => $models]); // i have a conver array to json object
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I really appreciate your time and effort. What I needed is to keep make and model in the same table and use 'make' instead of 'id'. something like (select model from cars where make=selected make). can you help please?